# Move folders from various locations to a specific folder -- Win. 8

Tags: windows-8, backup, external-hard-drive

I just purchased an external hard drive and was thinking about moving my movie backups over to it. The problem with this is that I didn't really take the time to organize my movie backups to begin with so I have various movie folders (different languages) all stacked up in a number of folders.

I was thinking of maybe creating a script that copies specific folders in X directory and move it to Y directory on the external. I don't mind getting the folder directories and copying / pasting it.

Is there any way I can do this?

Ex)

Original Folders:

C:\Users\Bob\Movies\Whatever1

C:\Users\Bob\Movies\Whatever2

C:\Users\Bob\Movies\Whatever3

Move to external hard drive E:\Hollywood\1985

Answer (score 1):

[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) is what you need. Search By path. Then Ctrl Select folders, Press Ctrl+C, Press Ctrl+V in target folder. Done.

Comment: Everything is a wonderful tool if you know the name of what you are looking for. Use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you could just have a couple simple lines

```
$paths = "C:\Users\Bob\Movies\Whatever1","C:\Users\Bob\Movies\Whatever2","C:\Users\Bob\Movies\Whatever3"
$targetDirectory = "E:\Hollywood\1985"
$paths | ForEach-Object{
    Copy-Item $_ $targetDirectory
}
```

Every path in `$paths` is run in a loop where it gets copied to `$targetDirectory`. You could change `Copy-Item` to `Move-Item` but having a copy is better that just moving them to the external drive since that is a single point of failure.

Also a good tool I use for stuff like this is [FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/fc_beta_en.htm) since it supports double pane view. Makes it easy to copy files from one directory to another.

[image]